# Scrollbar on mac OS mozilla firefox and mobile safari

Tags: css, macos, mobile, safari, scrollbar

Can someone help me with the scrollbar on Mac OS X in Mozilla firefox and in mobile safari?
scrollbar-color in css works only in windows machines, other js libraries not working on , always scrollbar has system default styles.
Maybe someone has already had some dealings with this?

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me without any problems. `::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb` `::-webkit-scrollbar-track` and `::-webkit-scrollbar`

More info [developer.mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

```css
div{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: yellow;
  overflow: auto;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #0a59e3;
    border-radius: 16px;
    box-shadow: inset 2px 2px 2px hsl(219deg 31% 32%), inset -2px -2px 2px rgb(18 24 38);
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #0f1520;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 1.65em;
    height: 1.65em;
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="visible-scrollbar">
  Etiam sagittis sem sed lacus laoreet, eu fermentum eros auctor.
  Proin at nulla elementum, consectetur ex eget, commodo ante.
  Sed eros mi, bibendum ut dignissim et, maximus eget nibh. Phasellus
  blandit quam turpis, at mollis velit pretium ut. Nunc consequat
  efficitur ultrices. Nullam hendrerit posuere est. Nulla libero
  sapien, egestas ac felis porta, cursus ultricies quam. Vestibulum
  tincidunt accumsan sapien, a fringilla dui semper in. Vivamus
  consectetur ipsum a ornare blandit. Aenean tempus at lorem sit
  amet faucibus. Curabitur nibh justo, faucibus sed velit cursus,
  mattis cursus dolor. Pellentesque id pretium est. Quisquebibendum ut dignissim et, maximus eget nibh. Phasellus
  blandit quam turpis, at mollis velit pretium ut. Nunc consequat
  efficitur ultrices. Nullam hendrerit posuere est. Nulla libero
  sapien, egestas ac felis porta, cursus ultricies quam. Vestibulum
  tincidunt accumsan sapien, a fringilla dui semper in. Vivamus
  consectetur ipsum a ornare blandit. Aenean tempus at lorem sit
  amet faucibus. Curabitur nibh justo, faucibus sed velit cursus,
  mattis cursus dolor. Pellentesque id pretium est. Quisquebibendum ut dignissim et, maximus eget nibh. Phasellus
  blandit quam turpis, at mollis velit pretium ut. Nunc consequat
  efficitur ultrices. Nullam hendrerit posuere est. Nulla libero
  sapien, egestas ac felis porta, cursus ultricies quam. Vestibulum
  tincidunt accumsan sapien, a fringilla dui semper in. Vivamus
  consectetur ipsum a ornare blandit. Aenean tempus at lorem sit
  amet faucibus. Curabitur nibh justo, faucibus sed velit cursus,
  mattis cursus dolor. Pellentesque id pretium est. Quisque
  convallis nisi a diam malesuada mollis. Aliquam at enim ligula.
</div>
```

Comment: It's not working on Mac OS X firefox :(

Comment: @arm-channel I have a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2017) it works without problems in google and safari

Comment: yes in google and safari it's works but not on Mozilla firefox